# Detect empty directory with Perl

Tags: perl, file, directory

What is an easy way to test if a folder is empty in perl? -s, and -z are not working.

Example:

```
#Ensure Apps directory exists on the test PC.
if ( ! -s $gAppsDir )
{ 
    die "\n$gAppsDir is not accessible or does not exist.\n"; 
}

#Ensure Apps directory exists on the test PC.
if ( ! -z $gAppsDir )
{ 
    die "\n$gAppsDir is not accessible or does not exist.\n"; 
}
```

These above, do not work properly to tell me that the folder is empty. Thanks!

---

Thanks all! I ended up using:

```
sub is_folder_empty { my $dirname = shift; opendir(my $dh, $dirname) or die "Not a directory"; 
return scalar(grep { $_ ne "." && $_ ne ".." } readdir($dh)) == 0; }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A little verbose for clarity, but:

```
sub is_folder_empty {
    my $dirname = shift;
    opendir(my $dh, $dirname) or die "Not a directory";
    return scalar(grep { $_ ne "." && $_ ne ".." } readdir($dh)) == 0;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
if (is_folder_empty($your_dir)) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: It's not as clear as it could be - no need for the `scalar`. The `grep` internals might be more clearly written as `not /^\.+$/`: `sub is_folder_empty { opendir my $dh, +shift or die $!; return grep { not /^\.+$/ } readdir $dh; }`

Comment: re "Not a directory": or doesn't exist or don't have permission, etc.  how about `or die "$dirname: $!"`

Comment: @Zaid ... shouldn't be treated specially.  and you now have it returning true (actually a count of contents) if it isn't empty

Comment: @Zaid: You seem to have confused 'clarity' and 'brevity'.  Also, `touch dir/....` fools your regular expression.

Comment: Clarity and brevity is good.  The solution does read all the file names in the directory, whereas at most three entries are needed ('.' and '..' probably appear first, and the next name indicates that the directory is not empty.  Fixing that defeats clarity, though.

Comment: Shouldn't the directory handle be closed? `closedir($dh)`

Comment: A good solution. Also, I would suggest to avoid the `grep` and use `File::Spec->no_upwards` instead

Comment: @Andre perl will close the filehandle once `$dh` goes out of scope, i.e. when `is_folder_empty` returns.

Answer (score 6):

Using `grep { ! /^[.][.]?\z/ } readdir $dir_h` can be problematic for performance in case the check is done many times and some directories may have many files.

It would be better to short-circuit the moment a directory entry other than `.` or `..` is found.

On Windows XP with ActiveState `perl` 5.10.1, the following sub seems to be twice as fast as the `grep` approach on my `$HOME` with 100 entries:

```
sub is_dir_empty {
    my ($dir) = @_;

    opendir my $h, $dir
        or die "Cannot open directory: '$dir': $!";

    while ( defined (my $entry = readdir $h) ) {
        return unless $entry =~ /^[.][.]?\z/;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @ysth `return ! defined List::Util::first { $_ !~ /^[.][.]?\z/ } readdir $h;` the disadvantage of that solution is, that it will read the whole directory entries to a list first. This can be slow for directories with many members.

Answer (score 4):

Or without any grepping or regular expressions - which rules out any chance of weird file names accidentally getting though.  Plus slightly faster is my testing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub is_dir_empty {
    return -1 if not -e $_[0];   # does not exist
    return -2 if not -d $_[0];   # in not a directory
    opendir my $dir, $_[0] or    # likely a permissions issue
        die "Can't opendir '".$_[0]."', because: $!\n";
    readdir $dir;
    readdir $dir;
    return 0 if( readdir $dir ); # 3rd times a charm
    return 1;
}

my @folders = qw( ./ ./empty ./hasonefile ./hastwofiles ./doesnotexist ./afile );
for my $folder ( @folders ) {
    print "Folder '$folder' ";
    my $rc = is_dir_empty( $folder );
    if( $rc == -1 ) {
        print "does not exist\n";
    } elsif( $rc == -2 ) {
        print "is not a directory\n";
    } elsif( !$rc ) {
        print "is not empty\n";
    } else {
        print "is empty\n";
    }
}
```

Pretty simple.  If you get three valid responses from a call to readdir, then you know there must be a file in there.  Regardless of what name the file may have - or the order in which the files are being processed.  Would have preferred something called 'is_dir_used' as I personally don't like the double-negative function name and return value.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. It is the only solution that does not read the whole directory content and also doesn't apply regexes that are not needed (as proven by this solution). I guess people might be worried, because this code snippet is longer than the others but that is only because *in addition* this solution also shows proper error handling with is another advantage in my opinion.

Comment: @josch no, the tests for names to ignore are needed.   Not all filesystems will have a .. in every directory, for example.

Comment: @ysth Isn't the `..` entry a property of the OS and not of the file system? Which ones do not have that?

Comment: @josch An ISO compliant or compatible OS, should support both the '.' and '..' for any mountable filesystem, and that covers just about every modern OS there is.  I have seen and used systems that did not support these - perhaps 25+ years ago, and none of those systems supported Perl - so this solution should be OK today.

Comment: It's safer to check the third return value for definedness -- `if readdir $dh` may fail if the directory happens to contain a file called `0`.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [`File::List`](http://search.cpan.org/~dopacki/File-List-0.3.1/List/List.pm) from cpan. It's overkill here, but can be handy for slightly more complex requests like test if a directory is empty with the meaning it contains only empty directories (ie: not files).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more consise algorithm using Perl v5.12 (from circa 2010).
At most, three reads of the directory are made.

- It does NOT read the whole directory.
- It handles non-Unix filesystems that do not have '..'; See 'find' '-noleaf'

##### Desc: return true if empty, false if not empty; die if opendir() error

```
sub is_dir_empty {
    use 5.012;      # so readdir assigns to $_ in a lone while test
    local($_);      # prevent side effects

    my $dir = shift // die "arg missing";

    opendir my $dh, $dir or die "opendir(..,$dir): $!";

    while ( readdir $dh ) {
        return 0  if ! /^ [.][.]? $/x;
    }

    return 1;
} # is_dir_empty()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Credit to DevShed](http://forums.devshed.com/perl-programming-6/check-if-directory-empty-or-not-510356.html)

```
if (scalar <directory/*>) {print qq|File Exists\n|}
```

---

#### Edit

To include hidden files:

```
@arr = <directory/* directory/.*>;
@arr = grep {!/^directory/[.]{1,2}$/} @arr;
if (@arr) { print qq|File or Directory Exists\n| }
```

---

Please read the comments as there have been good points made.  Despite the negative points this answer has received, it is still correct.

Comment: bad bad bad.  never use glob in scalar context unless you really know what you are doing.  that line, if called repeatedly, will return true once for each thing in directory, then will return false once, then start over.

Comment: I don't think that's true.  I think it will stop at the first file found, as mentioned in the forum it's similar to `-e` and equivalent to calling w/o `scalar`, both will stop at the first file found. `never use glob in scalar context unless you really know what you are doing` in this regard it's perfectly safe.  Not doing something for the sake of not doing it is bad advice.

Comment: try it.  the following will print File Exists twice, not three times: `mkdir directory; touch directory/a; touch directory/b; perl -we'for(1..3){if (scalar <directory/*>) {print qq|File Exists\n|}}'
`

Comment: a correct way to do it would be `if (()=<directory/*>)` but still suffers the flaw of not noticing files like directory/.foo

Comment: ysth: that is true and I never denied that.  I also agree, you should know what you're doing, but this is a perfect valid way to test if a directory is empty (it does not check for hidden files as you mentioned). -- your example is for a loop, however if you did `$x=<directory/*>;$y=<directory/*>;` then `$x` and `$y` would both be the same thing, the handle is recalled, otherwise (in a loop) the handle is left open and retrieves the next thing, so instead of `for` its better to use `while` - an end of file will be reached.

Comment: If you do use a for loop, you would want to assign the value to some variable ($foo) and put `next if ! scalar($foo);` at the beginning, but again a `for` loop is not advised here.  I'm keeping this answer here, despite the poor rating because it is valid, despite the nay-sayers.

Comment: I'll modify the answer if you want to include hidden files

Answer (score 0):

```
opendir(DIR,"DIR PATH") or die "Unable to open directory \"DIR PATH\" \n";
my @drList = readdir(DIR);
close(DIR);
if( grep(/\w/,@drList) ){ print "Not Empty\n" }
else { print "Empty\n" }
```

Comment: This will fail on directories that are not-empty but contain files that do not match `/\w/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  sub is_folder_empty {
        my $dirname = shift;
        my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*')->maxdepth(1)->in("$dirname");
        return $#files < 0;
    }
```

Comment: This will fail for non empty directories containing files that do not match `*`. For example files that start with a dot.