# Checking if a folder is empty (what are "." and "..")

Tags: perl

I'm new to perl and intended to check if a folder is empty. I found this function:

```
is_folder_empty {
    my $dirname = shift;
    opendir(my $dh, $dirname) or die "Not a directory";
    return scalar(grep { $_ ne "." && $_ ne ".." } readdir($dh)) == 0;
}
```

It's working fine but I don't understand why it's doing `grep { $_ ne "." && $_ ne ".." }`. What is the meaning of `.` and `..` here?

Comment: using Boolean Algebra, you are more or less correct, it could have rewritten as: `grep { not ( $_ eq '.' || $_ eq '..' ) }` See 'De Morgans Law'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you looked at [Detect empty directory with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493482/detect-empty-directory-with-perl).

Even an empty directory contains the `.` and `..` directories.

`.` means the current directory.

`..` means the parent directory.

So your function is excluding those two results, because they will always be there.

Answer (score 3):

A directory has alway an entry . (this Directory) and .. (parent Directory).
The code you are mentioned reads all entries of the Directory, and if there only These entries it is empty.

Hope i am understandable